# Building a Q&A platform that is scalable

Tags: architecture, scalability

I am planning to use open source, SQL/NoSQL? MVC? CQRS? caching? hadoop? Bigtable? S3?
By scalable I mean supporting +1M users

This is a social-change venture (not-for-profit), including geo-location and social networking features.

Comment: I think my dictionary's definition of "subjective" actually has "What is the best architecture?" as an example.

Comment: This is too vague and subjective to answer.

Comment: You're right, just changed that! thx :)

Comment: "SQL/NoSQL? MVC? CQRS? caching? hadoop? Bigtable? S3?" Are you trying to help me win Buzzword Bingo? Do you know what they are and what they're for? Why would a Q&A site need geolocation? Maybe you should flesh out your requirements first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on your  scalability goals, you may start with Mysql and end up with noSQL systems (such as MongoDB, cassandra etc)..
MVC is good anyway for layer separation
CQRS is interesting especially to scale up reads vs writes independently, but requires a good thinking about the UI
Caching is a must IMO, Varnish, memcached and memcacheDB (persistent)

Answer (score 1):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/